# How does morphToMany work here?

Tags: php, laravel

I've been trying to figure this many to many relationship inside of my transactions method for my model most of the day and it has me stumbled.

```
class Ticket extends Model {

public function transactions() {
    return $this->morphToMany(
        Transaction::class,
        "product",
        "products_to_transactions"
    )->withPivot("quantity");
}

}
```

I know we are looking for a many to many relationship with common columns of product_id and product_type right and that comes from product, right? I'm just not sure as this isn't my code. Any explanation would be helpful in my further understanding. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For your scenario, the following is what each of the arguments are for:

Arg1 - Model Name

Arg2 - Table Name

Arg3 - Foreign Key Name

Comment: @wowzuzz `morphToMany` represents a many to many relationship, where the owning model is completely dynamic, it is part of polymorphism